# What is the experience of travelling while working on a cruise ship?

Tags: international-travel, cruising, working-holiday, around-the-world

Something that many people have on their to-do list would be a round-the-world trip. The typical holiday or itinerary for these types of trips tend to be very hectic and expensive.

I have contemplated trying to find a job on a cruise trip in order to reduce the cost of travelling around the world while also being able to enjoy the experience of seeing lots of different places around the world.

I am interested in those that have either worked on a cruise ship on a round-the-world trip or those that have spoken to the employees on a cruise ship as to what the experience is like, and whether you can really enjoy it while also working (i.e. given the number of hours required to work, amount of free time available, time between the cruise ship moving onto different places).

As mentioned in a related question before, there is a difference between working as a staff on a cruise ship versus being a crew, but this question simply takes into consideration the following:

- money that you can earn/spend while working in any position on a cruise ship
- amount of free time that you can spend offshore and exploring the location before the cruise ship moves on
- amount of work hours required to ensure that you don't feel too tired and have enough energy to want to do other things
- any other considerations that might make it a good experience (or bad experience)

BONUS: If anyone has an inside tip on how to get a job working on a cruise ship that would be great!

Comment: There's not much round-the-world'ing on a cruise ship -- more like a small closed loop.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, though not common, there are around the world cruises and those have people working on them for the whole trip and more.

Comment: Yep. The majority though are the shorter type, which means the majority of job openings/opportunities will be on the shorter sort of cruise.

Comment: Micheal Lai, what kind of jobs would you be able to do? Hotel staff, (kitchen, cleaning, bar tender and so on), crew (engine, seaman, mate, and such) or entertainer? It makes a difference in whether you can get such a job and whether you can get a round the world trip.

Comment: When you're on a contract, you might get part of a day off, not a full day because ships run 24/7 based on what I've read.

Comment: @Willeke I am thinking of jobs that involve entertaining people on the cruise, probably teaching guests something or run classes/workshops.

Comment: @MichaelLai, can you please edit that into your question? (I do not have high hopes, but do not know enough about that class of jobs.)

Comment: Related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/getting-work-on-a-cruise-ship-in-order-to-travel?rq=1